# Do I need permission to a website in creating a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I plan to create an app, specifically a chrome extension to the Stack Overflow website. Do I need to ask permission from the Stack Overflow team in order to publish this app? If so, does anyone know how? Thank you.

Comment: From a technical standpoint, no, but you should consider the terms of service of Stack Overflow, and the data flowing within to be sure you are compliant with them.

Comment: Often it's forbidden to have the product/site name in your extension's name.